# Does searching give any priority to my favorited questions/answers?

Tags: support, search, bookmarks

When searching any topic on Stack Overflow, do responses give priority to questions/answers that I already favorited?

I have some questions that come up far enough apart that I'd've forgotten my favorited answer that I can refer to. Once I find the answer again, I realize I had saved that or another answer previously.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Search doesn't prioritize your favorited/saved posts. You could apply the [`in:saves`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=in%3asaves&mixed=0) search filter to show results within your favorites/saves.

If you want to search answers you have previously posted instead, use [`is:a user:me`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=is%3aa%20user%3ame&mixed=0).

You can use [my userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) to see what other search options are available to you.

Comment: This is all not user friendly at all.  I mean search should be easier to use and more intuitive...boy how hard it is to search for my own favorites...

Comment: This is not working now, as per help [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) the following works: `in:saves`.

Comment: @DavidLeal funnily enough, my userscript was updated long ago before this answer, which I had forgotten about until you commented.

Comment: Search is notoriously neglected by the company. There is also the [dupe manager user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/9400/duplicate-manager-with-automatic-closure-and-duplicate-list-editing) (I have not tried it yet).

Comment: You can favorite answers now.