# A search box to narrow the number of questions shown under your profiles saves, votes, questions, etc

Tags: feature-request, search, bookmarks, search-box, saves

I'll save/vote on a question if it helped me.

Later I might have difficulty remembering something from the post.

With no search feature, the process of finding the question again in my bookmarks/votes can be extremely difficult and time consuming.

---

This is the saves tab

[image]

A search bar could be added, that would enable people to filter results within any of those categories at the top of the image above, to reduce the number of results that someone would have to sift through. The search bar could search for tags, a phrase from the title, etc.

This could cut down the number of results from something like 106 (like above) to about 6 or so (much more efficient)

Adding a search bar would make the bookmarks tab look like the below picture instead

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does searching give any priority to my favorited questions/answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378785/does-searching-give-any-priority-to-my-favorited-questions-answers)

Comment: It's almost a solution, I don't know where to find all the options that aren't `infavorites:` though, like `invotes:` for example, and I agree with the comment on that answer that this isn't very user friendly

Comment: Hmm... Related: [Search for questions/answers you voted on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291357/1364007) and [Search among posts you've voted for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89555/284827) (neither have answers).

Comment: I have this cumbersome approach of saving all the posts I've voted on locally. Else, I would never be able to find that one that I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah thats related, it doesn't look like it was implemented

Comment: @Scratte I think I'm going to have to go through all of my votes, bookmarks ... and bookmark them in my browser. If SO was open source, I feel like it might be just as much work to implement this feature myself.

Comment: I've done it manually. Ever time I vote I paste the link (and some other information) into my file. The issue with just having bookmarks is that sometimes I don't remember the title, but I do remember the username. Or when I voted, like end of August.

Comment: And here I am, using my browser's bookmark/favorites function, that has search built into the browser UI. What a maroon...

Comment: I've been on SO for less than 1year already have 132 bookmarks. Any plan to introduce bookmarks subcategories

Comment: @Sam: You forgot to edit the previous `106` (Bookmarks) into `138` (Saves), oops...! + You still mention `bookmark(s)` in your Post x2...

Comment: @pippo1980: It happened in September 2022: *"[Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves)"*

Comment: doesn't the site search solve this problem? If anything a search bar in this location should direct you to a standard search result page, not filter the results on the profile... thus *teaching* how to use our site search.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yep using them and enjoying it , thanks a lot

Comment: @KevinB What if you want to filter the results on a specific profile though, and only search something like saves

Comment: The site search supports that, minus you can't see other people's saves. (even with this feature you wouldn't see other people's saves)