# Users should have an option to categorize bookmarked questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

Whenever a question is bookmarked, it is being thrown into the general pool of user's bookmarked questions.

It would be useful to have an option to choose which custom category the bookmarked question should go to- Java, Kubernetes, Bash, Python, etc..

Something similar to YouTube playlists - when you are adding a video to a playlist, you are being asked to select one from the list of existing playlists, and if the playlist doesn't exist yet, the user is allowed to create one.

Comment: You can use search to search your bookmarked questions with a specific tag: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inbookmarks%3A2056914+%5Bjava%5D

Comment: There's a related [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403378/a-search-box-to-narrow-the-number-of-questions-shown-under-your-profiles-bookmar) that you might find interesting.

Comment: I've very much like something like this. I have a mix of duplicate targets and some questions that are of interest to me in my bookmarks. I'd really like if I had several categories of bookmarks to properly separate them.

Comment: Your browser will also give you ways to organize tabs.

Comment: @philipxy a single browser on a single device. Unless you enable syncing of profiles between different devices but it still only works with the same browser. And that still relies on using *the same* profile to sync between. On different devices, sometimes I use different browsers, sometimes the same browser but different profiles.

Comment: Some feature requests on MSO in the same ballpark: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944) | [Categorising favourite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251065) | [Adding a note to a favourite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8619) | [Is there any way I can organize my favorite questions on StackOverflow using self-defined categories?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178118) | [Adding a note to a favourite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8619)

Comment: [Better favourites organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3912) | [Allow grouping of favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125180)

Answer (score 2):

With the launch of the [Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) recently, this is now possible. Custom lists can be created to organize your favorite saved content (now supporting saving answers as well!) As such, I've added the [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) label.