# How can I search within in a specific saved list?

Tags: support, feature-request, saves

StackOverflow and StackExchange have the feature to save a post and put it in a specific list for later use. I find this feature very helpful but I am not sure how to search with a specific save list. For example if I have two lists `for later` (the default list, which is used e.g. for posts that I want to review later) and `C++ skills`. I want to be able to search only in the list of `C++ skills`. I have read the help and found the `in:saves` operator, which limits the search to the posts I have saved, but I have not yet found out how to search within a particular list of saves only.

Is it possible and if it is not, would it be a reasonable feature request?

EDIT:

I've closed the question myself by mistake. The related question specifically asks for a search box to achieve the goal while I am more asking for a search operator like `in:saves[c++skills]` to do so, so I don't believe it's an exact duplicate.

Comment: Related broad feature request: [A search box to narrow the number of questions shown under your profiles saves, votes, questions, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403378/a-search-box-to-narrow-the-number-of-questions-shown-under-your-profiles-saves)